# Extracting QuickTime Files from a Resource and converting them into Separate Files

Tags: vb.net, file-io, quicktime

I have a resource file for a program, and i have determined that the resource file just a big string of files glued together whole, i know that the movies contained in the file are quicktime mov. Where can i find information on the quicktime header? and how can i determine the length of a file once i find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QuickTime File Format Specification is located here:

[developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/qtff.pdf](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/qtff.pdf)